# Por qué en el segundo ciclo del algoritmo no acepta la funcion gets(name);?

Tags: c, while

Estoy empezando a estudiar programación en C.
Haciendo un ejercicio me encontré con un error que no logro saber qué es.
El ejercicio trata de un programa que tiene un ciclo con do while, en el primer momento que se ejecuta todo funciona correctamente, pero en el segundo ciclo que repite el mismo código ya no reconoce el comando gets(); y simplemente se salta a otra línea que es un scanf(); por lo que no permite ingresar la cadena de caracteres.
He leido algo del puntero de los caracteres pero no entiendo bien el concepto aún, no sé si tenga algo que ver con eso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define grades 5


char name[20];
float finalGrade;
float result =0;
char answer;

 void avarage(){


  float grade[grades];
  for(int i = 0; i< grades; i++){
    printf("\nIngrese la nota %i del alumno: ", i+1);
    scanf("%f",&grade[i]);
    result +=grade[i];
  }
    result /=grades;

 }

 void status(){

    if(result >= 7)
    printf("\n\t**********************\nFELICIDADES EL ESTUDIANTE APROBO EL CURSO\n\t******************\n");
    else
     printf("\n\t---------------------\nLO SENTIMOS EL ALUMNO DEBE REPETIR EL CURSO\n\t---------------------\n");
 }


int main (){

 do{

    system("cls");
    printf("Entrega de notas de los alumnos. \n\n");
    printf("Ingrese el nombre del alumno a evaluar: ");
    gets(name);
    avarage();
    printf("\nEl promedio del alumno %s fue de %.2f sobre 10.\n",name,result);
    status();
    result = 0;
    printf("\nDesea continuar evaluando otro alumno?.");
    printf("\nPresione cualquier tecla y enter para continuar, o la tecla S para salir: ");
    scanf(" %c",&answer);


}
while (answer != 's');

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Si bien C podría considerarse más sencillo, te aconsejo que aprendas C++. Así puedes usar todo lo que la librería estándar te brinda e ir conociendo poco a poco diferentes conceptos. Como los punteros.

Comment: @Mateo C tiene su biblioteca estándar y se la puede estudiar y por supuesto, también se comprender el tema de los punteros sin tocar C++.

Comment: @MrDave1999 gracias por informarme. Puesto que yo aprendí C++. Aunque sé que hay diferencias importantes con C, no acostumbro a programar en él y hay cosas que se me escapan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que `gets` lee hasta un salto de línea pero `scanf` lo deja. Entonces debes quitar ese salto de línea de algún modo. Una manera es llamando a la función `getchar` antes de `gets`.

Por otro lado, la función `gets` está obsoleta. Así que te recomiendo que uses `fgets` en su lugar. Además te da más control. Un ejemplo:

```
char buffer[50];

fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
```

Fuentes:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28719622
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5918091

Comment: Muchas gracias, no se me hubiera ocurrido usar ese getchar( ); funcionó correctamente. En cuanto al gets lo tendré en cuenta.